# Where I can find the prefix of multistore prestathsop tables

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I need to integrate some module to prestashop. I need to know how I can programmatically find all multishop names and db prefixes.
I know That i can find the names of all shops in table ps_shop.
I know that I can find the main db prefix in parameters.php.
But where located db prefixes of other shops i dont know.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to find other tables by their **suffix**, in your case by **_shop**, but you can get all tables with this code easily:

```php
$tables = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SHOW TABLES LIKE "%_shop";');
$tables = array_column($tables, 'Tables_in_'._DB_NAME_.' (%_shop)');

var_dump($tables);
```

Comment: Rolige, I purpose that you mean there no ability associate the shop name and the prefix of tables?

Comment: On a multi-store there is NO other prefixes, as much as the database and tables are the same for all shops.